# Not able to connect to smtp.gmail.com

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i using following java program to send mail from gmail account

```
final String username = "user@gmail.com";
final String password = "password";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session =
    Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

try {

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user@gmail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                          InternetAddress.parse("user@live.in"));
    message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
    message.setText("Dear Bhavik Patel," +
                    "\n\n This is just a mail!");

    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

i have also tried port 587 but it is not working

```
Transport.send(message);
```

at this execution tries to connect and send

i don't know what is wrong with it. i also tried telnet and from there i am able to connect

**Exception:**

java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

Comment: how are you determining "it is not working"?  Error message, timeout, exception, what?

Comment: The `SSL` properties (for port 465) are slightly different.  Have a look at [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) for more details (note, I've not tried it)

Comment: timeout it is throwing after 6 minute

Comment: @MadProgrammer let me try with second example in your link

Comment: Double ping, no issues (SSL and TLS).  What version of javamail are you using?  I was using 1.4.7 and 1.5.0

Comment: for SSL i got this exception "javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: "

Answer (score 0):

I m using the port `587` and i m able to send/recieve mails..or you can set the property

**mail.smtp.timeout** to **25000** and try if it is a timeout exception..

Comment: if i use 587 then it show 'unable send command to SMTP'... does firewall or any block system affect the program?

Comment: mostly its because of firewall or an antivirus program that can block u from sending email messages..if u have installed or enable them try to disable those programs..and try sending it..

Comment: is there another way to do this?

Comment: [Refer this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) for sending simple mail, mail with attachment and html email messages..

Answer (score 0):

Try these JavaMail FAQ entries:

- [How do I access Gmail with JavaMail?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail)
- [How do I debug problems connecting to my mail server?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug)

You need to set "mail.smtp.ssl.enable", not starttls.

Answer (score 0):

There are slight differences between my `send_mail` code and yours, but I couldn't find out what is it that your problem caused by. Here is my code:

```
 public static int sendMail(String SMTPServer,
                    String Sender,
                    String Recipient,
                    String Subject,
                    String Body,
                    String ErrorMessage,
                    String Attachments) {
// Error status;
int ErrorStatus = 0;

// Create some properties and get the default Session;
final String username = Sender;
final String password = "passwd";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
  });

try {
   // Create a message.
   MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

   // extracts the senders and adds them to the message.
   // Sender is a comma-separated list of e-mail addresses as per RFC822.
   {
      InternetAddress[] TheAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(Sender);
      msg.addFrom(TheAddresses);
   }

   // Extract the recipients and assign them to the message.
   // Recipient is a comma-separated list of e-mail addresses as per RFC822.
   {
      InternetAddress[] TheAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(Recipient);
      msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,TheAddresses);
   }

   // Subject field
   msg.setSubject(Subject);

   // Create the Multipart to be added the parts to
   Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

   // Create and fill the first message part
   {
      MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
      mbp.setText(Body);

      // Attach the part to the multipart;
      mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
   }

   // Add the Multipart to the message
   msg.setContent(mp);

   // Set the Date: header
   msg.setSentDate(new Date());

   // Send the message;
   Transport.send(msg);
} catch (MessagingException MsgException) {
    System.out.println("blows here");
    ErrorMessage = MsgException.toString();
    Exception TheException = null;
    if ((TheException = MsgException.getNextException()) != null)
     ErrorMessage += "\n" + TheException.toString();
     ErrorStatus = 1;
}
System.out.println(ErrorMessage);
return ErrorStatus;
}
```

I've been using this code without any problem.

Hope it helps,